# Recommendations for intermediate flashcard deck?

Tags: vocabulary, resources

Can anyone recommend a flashcard deck to expand my vocabulary at the intermediate level?  I use Anki for learning vocab in Japanese study, and I've looked for an intermediate Italian deck, but the Anki Italian-English decks out there seem to consist of all very basic words, whole sentences, or specialized vocabulary (medical etc.).  It doesn't have to be Anki; another site or tool would be fine.

Thanks in advance.

**ETA:** Thanks, all.  I'll check out the vocab list linked below and make an Anki deck of the unfamiliar words.  I also picked up a DK visual dictionary—the Japanese edition helped me round out my vocab in that language.

Comment: It is not already in flashcard format, but [this](https://www.internazionale.it/opinione/tullio-de-mauro/2016/12/23/il-nuovo-vocabolario-di-base-della-lingua-italiana) should useful to, at worst, prepare your own set of flashcards (it is a list of the 7000 most important words of the Italian language prepared by an important Italian linguists)

Comment: (the 2000 "fundamental" words are in boldface, the 3000 words "in high usage" are in the normal font and the "widespread" ones are in italic)

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!